# Why does Excel treat the comma as a number?

Tags: excel

If I input =numbervalue(4), I get the unsurprising result "4," if I input =numbervalue("m"), I get the unsurprising result "#value!," if I input =numbervalue("."), I get the unsurprising result "#value!," if I input =numbervalue(","), I get the very surprising result "0." Why is this and are there other characters that do this?

Comment: I will guess that is because the comma, in your regional settings, is a group separator. These are ignored by `NUMBERVALUE` (unless it appears after the decimal symbol).

Comment: ^^^ as explained in the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/numbervalue-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879)

Comment: Your region may be Spain or some European countries change that to India or US

Comment: My regional settings are normal U.S., but that still doesn't explain why it's being converted to a number. The example in the documentation does not convert the comma to an Arabic numeral zero character. As it turns out,  the double dash function does essentially the same thing as numbervalue, but correctly recognizes the comma as a non-number. To be clear, the numbervalue function in my example is not treating the comma as a separator, but as the number zero (0).

Comment: Yes, but since it ignores the separator, the rest of the cell evaluates to a null string `""`. According to the documentation, a `""` will evaluate to zero.

Comment: @Rod Rosenfield  thanks for the clear answer. That does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> If the Decimal_separator and Group_separator arguments are not specified, separators from the current locale are used.

You state you are using U.S. settings.   Therefore your group separator is `,`

> If the group separator occurs before the decimal separator in the Text argument, the group separator is ignored.

As the only character in the string, the `,` is therefore ignored.  That leaves you with an empty string

> If an empty string ("") is specified as the Text argument, the result is 0.

So, as expected `=numbervalue(",")` returns `0`